# Calculation of cross entropy

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to calculate the cross-entropy(q,p) for the following discrete distributions:

```
p = [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]

q = [0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
```

and using the numpy library:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.6])
q = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 0.5])

cross_entropy = -np.sum(q*np.log(p))
```

which outputs

```
0.857399
```

But I'm trying to work out the equation by hand and I'm getting a different result:

```
-(0*log(0.1) + 0.5*log(0.3) + 0.5*log(0.6))
```

and I calculate the result being:

```
0.37236
```

I was wondering which part of the manual calculation I did wrong. Pardon my awful maths if i made any silly mistake. :'>

Answer (score 1):

Your manual calculation uses log with base $10$:

```
IN: -(0*np.log10(0.1) + 0.5*np.log10(0.3) + 0.5*np.log10(0.6))
OUT: 0.372363747448347
```

However, `np.log` is the natural logarithm ([from the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html)):

> numpy.log
> numpy.log(x, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj]) = <ufunc 'log'>
>
> Natural logarithm, element-wise.
>
> The natural logarithm log is the inverse of the exponential function, so that log(exp(x)) = x. The natural logarithm is logarithm in base e.